# Prove it is the incenter.

Tags: geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle. Let $H$  be the foot of the perpendicular from A to BC. Let $K$ be the foot of the  the perpendicular of $H$ to $AB$, let $L$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $H$ to $AC$. Let $AH$ intersect the circumcircle of $ \triangle ABC$ in $T$, and let the line through $K$ and $L$ intersect the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ in $P$ and $Q$. Prove that $H$ is the incenter of $\triangle PQT$.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be using same names for both points and lines. Could you clarify what is what in this problem?

Comment: Ah yes, I'll edit it

Comment: You must assume that $\triangle ABC$'s non-acute angle, if any, is at $A$. If $B$ or $C$ is obtuse, then $H$ is actually an *excenter* of $\triangle PQT$.

Comment: @Blue yes, can you solve it?

Comment: @wowlolbrommer: I haven't solved it yet. Where did you get this problem? From a textbook, or perhaps from a contest? Knowing the difficulty level could be helpful in deciding how to approach the problem.

Comment: I found it in a training booklet for geometry. It is from the Russian Sharygin competition, but I cannot find the solution online.

Comment: @Blue, are you making any progress with this problem. i have made some progress but with heavy trig.

Comment: @abel: I have a brute-force coordinate argument that gets me somewhere, but I'm not yet seeing the *good* approach.

Comment: @Blue, i don't think this is true.

Comment: @abel: My (and @Jack's) GeoGebra sketches demonstrate that the result is (probably) true. My coordinates-based argument proves the result, but right now it's too ugly to present.

Comment: @Blue, if you have time, can you please check my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any triangle the orthocenter and the circumcenter are isogonal conjugates. Since $AKHL$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, this implies that the perpendicular to $PQ$ through $A$ passes through the circumcenter of $ABC$, $O$. This implies $\widehat{POA}=\widehat{AOQ}$, so $\widehat{PTA}=\widehat{ATQ}$, and $AP=AQ$.
Let $A'$ be the symmetric of $H$ with respect to $A$. If we manage to prove $AP=AH$, then the perpendicular $l_P$ to $HP$ through $P$ and the perpendicular $l_Q$ to $HQ$ through $Q$ meet on $A'$, so $PTQ$ is the orthic triangle of the triangle $\Delta$ delimited by $l_P,l_Q$ and the perpendicular $l_T$ to $HT$ through $T$. This gives that $H$ is the orthocenter of $\Delta$, hence the incenter of $PTQ$.

[image]

The best way I found so far to prove $AP=AH$ is to use some trigonometry, but I think there are more clever ways.

**Edit:** Thanks to [wowlolbrommer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/204109/wowlolbrommer), here it is a clever way: $AP=AQ$ implies $\widehat{AQL}=\widehat{ACQ}$, hence $AQ^2=AL\cdot AC$. By Euclid's first theorem, $AL\cdot AC = AH^2$, hence $AP=AQ=AH$ and we're done.

Comment: if my figure is any guide, i don't that $AP = AH.$

Comment: @abel: I do not understand you. It is true that $AP=AH$, the only issue is that I have not found a nice proof of it, yet.

Comment: AH/AC=AL/AH and AQ/AL=AC/AQ so AH=AQ=AP

Comment: Assuming the result is true, then it's definitely also true that $AP=AH$. This is, by interesting coincidence, the upshot of [the Lemma in my answer to the recent Japanese Theorem question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1086195/409).

Comment: nice. AHC and ALH are similar for the first equality, AQL and ACQ re similar for the 2nd: QAL=CAQ, LQA=PQA=APQ=QCA

Comment: Also apparently it holds that for the midpoint M of an arc AB and I the orthocenter of a triangle ABC with C on the circle, MA=MB=MI

Comment: @wowlolbrommer: many thanks for your insights, now we have a complete elementary proof.

Comment: sorry about my comment. i found my error.

Comment: What was it? @JackD'Aurizio actually the construction you made proves the fact I stated